# Conditionally, and inline, add a property to an object, in a type safe way

Tags: typescript

**The objective**

The objective is to create an object while conditionally adding properties. The following rules apply:

1. it is not allowed to end up with the optional property set to
   undefined.
2. this must be done inline (so e.g. no loops / .reduce etc
   to construct the object)

**Two scenarios**

Consider the following code:

```
interface User {
  readonly firstName: string
  readonly lastName: string
}
interface ParitalUser {
  readonly firstName?: string
  readonly lastName?: string
}

const updateLastName = false

// SCENARIO 1
// create a user and conditionally add a name property
const partialUserA: ParitalUser = {
  ...(updateLastName ? { lastName: 'Doe' } : {}),
}

// i want the following assertion pass (so 'userA' should not have a property 'name' if addName is false)
console.assert(!('lastName' in partialUserA))

// but this is not type safe:
const partialUserB: ParitalUser = {
  ...(Math.random() < 0.5 ? { lastName: 'Doe' } : {}),
  ...(Math.random() < 0.5 ? { age: 21 } : {}), // should be an error, but isn't!
}

// SCENARIO 2
// i know I can do this
const partialUserC: ParitalUser = {
  lastName: updateLastName ? 'Doe' : undefined,
}

// this is type safe:
const partialUserB: ParitalUser = {
  lastName: updateLastName ? 'Doe' : undefined,
  age: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 21 : undefined, // is an error (as it should be) 
}

// but the this assertion doesn't pass anymore
console.assert(!('lastName' in partialUserC))
```

(playground, to play around with, can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=57&pc=55#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnJQRwAmA9iADYCeyMwU6YAcnALYQBcyTUoA5vkLFyVWpThNWHbrwG4AvrlCRYiFAAU4fMHEoYseAkVIUadBlPYQA-LLB8Qg4yLPjJLa3Z4P5S3AgUTMgArgAOJHCQADIe0igAvHR6mLi4APTpyADKAMIAoswAggBKAJIA8sgAjBlZCCaQyHChmFDNICTIgZ3AYMAUeuakXS0g1shhUGRh0GDUAUFgk9r9egZQRdxaOuttyElGyAB0pwAU4ZExcRM2OMgSVjLIAOQAImQQL8gKyNzYCgAlAAaRRpTLIYDIADucHAyDAAAsUDAyJRKGRoQJmug2v0KCtccgzugyK8Qm0it90IiyCFKF0QGRloi4AA3FAtKYzOa0F7jDjfYAwZokEjxSHoZKUTCAxYgUmUCDHSR4s4AQjOL0enkFkJAKyga30lMBcrqyAARiFlkjgFL7cgmbbqLMeHAYFx5cEwqtgHtoAAhbbaPoB9qHISnY5nACyUURxygcPIbDOgOQAB5kAAGY4AVmQd2wDxuz3en2+v3+QNBBGjcYTSZTZDTGezecLxea-C4yAATNUfn8cLXkBCaXSGVbOQboNMoMCrTbJSAXmB1WCLXlCqVKgOLVCANZM6HIMrdOHIcgIxH273LX1G-0m6C5EO7V8RnBCHXxbiXFEECxE8KB3BWXwjiEnQQPQIAQCQoL+BCdoOlK8xuugHpej0Pp+uGwbIDsYZfgcP4EH+1gAREQEgbqYGvB8kEATBcEIXWPZ9vGSLNp0rbplmuYFkWA5DixJCwaA7HjlkjpXvOZDtGckiQssk70l0loQBmW4QtatrIrecm4nMAwGuQEDoGuj6qh01BsIpEDemiyqqnMGpapReqgIaxobLkZppLhywUtAAAqZCoDRkDcBsZFHPQjD0dwLwAGLJiAR4vBxXl9i82RsH0iLZVuwWtNAWxoPskb1qcoVQBFUVXBAHHRk+fmUkhFpaYEHBSiWiWgSl6VwllS65SlBVFVWQVLOVUDvlVWA1ScdVtI10UtVGpztS+-ldXpEC9ZZ9yDclrwjZl2WlkNoSsVJXQKEAA))

**The problem**

- `SCENARIO 1` leads to an object without a property `lastName`, but it is not type safe
- `SCENARIO 2` is type safe, but it leads to an object with an undefined property `lastName` (see rule 1)

**But why?**

Consider the following code:

```
const userToUpdate: User = {
  firstName: 'Frank',
  lastName: 'Smith',
}

const userA: User = {
  ...userToUpdate,
  ...partialUserA,
}
// becomes { firstName: 'Frank', lastName: 'Smith' }

const userC: User = {
  ...userToUpdate,
  ...partialUserC,
}
// becomes { firstName: 'Frank', lastName: undefined }
```

(playground, to play around with, can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=57&pc=55#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnJQRwAmA9iADYCeyMwU6YAcnALYQBcyTUoA5vkLFyVWpThNWHbrwG4AvrlCRYiFAAU4fMHEoYseAkVIUadBlPYQA-LLB8Qg4yLPjJLa3Z4P5S3AgUTMgArgAOJHCQADIe0igAvHR6mLi4APTpyADKAMIAoswAggBKAJIA8sgAjBlZCCaQyHChmFDNICTIgZ3AYMAUeuakXS0g1shhUGRh0GDUAUFgk9r9egZQRdxaOuttyElGyAB0pwAU4ZExcRM2OMgSVjLIAOQAImQQL8gKyNzYCgAlAAaRRpTLIYDIADucHAyDAAAsUDAyJRKGRoQJmug2v0KCtccgzugyK8Qm0it90IiyCFKF0QGRloi4AA3FAtKYzOa0F7jDjfYAwZokEjxSHoZKUTCAxYgUmUCDHSR4s4AQjOL0enkFkJAKyga30lMBcrqyAARiFlkjgFL7cgmbbqLMeHAYFx5cEwqtgHtoAAhbbaPoB9qHISnY5nACyUURxygcPIbDOgOQAB5kAAGY4AVmQd2wDxuz3en2+v3+QNBBGjcYTSZTZDTGezecLxea-C4yAATNUfn8cLXkBCaXSGVbOQboNMoMCrTbJSAXmB1WCLXlCqVKgOLVCANZM6HIMrdOHIcgIxH273LX1G-0m6C5EO7V8RnBCHXxbiXFEECxE8KB3BWXwjiEnQQPQIAQCQoL+BCdoOlK8xuugHpej0Pp+uGwbIDsYZfgcP4EH+1gAREQEgbqYGvB8kEATBcEIXWPZ9vGSLNp0rbplmuYFkWA5DixJCwaA7HjlkjpXvOZDtGckiQssk70l0loQBmW4QtatrIrecm4nMAwGuQEDoGuj6qh01BsIpEDemiyqqnMGpapReqgIaxobLkZppLhywUtAAAqZCoDRkDcBsZFHPQjD0dwLwAGLJiAR4vBxXl9i82RsH0iLZVuwWtNAWxoPskb1qcoVQBFUVXBAHHRk+fmUkhFpaYEHBSiWiWgSl6VwllS65SlBVFVWQVLOVUDvlVWA1ScdVtI10UtVGpztS+-ldXpEC9ZZ9yDclrwjZl2WlkNoSsVJXQKEAA))

The intended use of all of this is to construct partial objects which represent properties that need to be updated.

`userC`, which was 'updated' using an object containing an `undefined` property, gets this property incorrectly overwritten. `userA` is constructed properly using `partialUserA` but this was not (see above) a type safe operation.